# why to put the name of the css selector before hashtag div#?

Tags: css, selector, hashtag

Actually, I want to know the difference between:

```
#content{some CSS rules}
```

and

```
div#content{some CSS rules}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one selects any element with the ID `content`.

The second one selects any `div` element with the ID `content`.

[MDN: Writing efficient CSS - How the style system matches rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS#How_the_Style_System_Matches_Rules)

Comment: It is more specific yes. Aside from increasing specificity there is litte practical reason to use `element#id` because ID's must be unique.

Comment: ok, let's say i have just one div with id #content, is it better to call it div#content or #content, or they're the same?

Comment: Better to just do #content

Comment: @SPrince see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS#How_the_Style_System_Matches_Rules

Comment: @SPrince by following the principle of not being over-specific.